# What does exactly mean by the term repository in git?

Tags: git, github, repository, dvcs

I'm trying to learn git.

I read few tutorials. Everywhere I got confused with the actual meaning of this term called **'Repository'**.

See the below definitions :

> A repository contains a directory named .git, where git keeps all of
>   its metadata for the repository. The content of the .git directory are
>   private to git.

So, my question is whether the directory which contains entire project (i.e. all the files of my project) along with the `.git` directory (usually it's hidden by default) is called **the Repository** of only the `.git` folder present within my project folder is called **the Repository**?

Comment: If speaking of the remote repository, then conceptually you only need to view it as the place where the actual branches and commits live.  Locally, yes you could say that the `.git` folder is the repository, though I usually see this term being used in the remote sense.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this in this way: The folder containing your project files (all the code) is the code repository. The `.git` folder that contains the Git metadata is the Git repository. The Git repository *corresponds* to the contents of the code repository.

In general, when someone says "Repository", it usually means the code repository (including the `.git` folder, if the code base is version-controlled). When "Repository" is said in terms of Git, it technically means the `.git` folder and its contents.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both are right.

In [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), it says, "This leads us to the three main sections of a Git project: the Git directory, the working tree, and the staging area." There is a picture which says ".git directory (Repository)". From this we can say a repository is `.git`, where Git stores the metadata and object database for your project.

However, there is evidence that proves a repository includes more than `.git`. A Git repository can be either bare or non-bare. What is a bare repository? It is [a repository that doesn’t contain a working directory](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server). So a non-bare repository contains a working directory. Besides, let's take a look at a Git submodule. What is a submodule? [A submodule is a repository embedded inside another repository](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_description). A bare repository can't be added as a submodule. And the operation to add a submodule must be in a work tree of the super project.

As to the difference between a working directory and a work tree, it's another story. There are [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128500/working-tree-vs-working-directory).